# ValueError: 'CartPole DQN model/' is not a valid root scope name

Tags: python, openai-gym

I am following this blog- https://www.pylessons.com/CartPole-reinforcement-learning to run a deep Q learning example.

while running below command in DQNAgent class in replay() function -

```
  target = self.model.predict(state)
```

getting this error-

ValueError: 'CartPole DQN model/' is not a valid root scope name. A root scope name has to match the following pattern: ^[A-Za-z0-9.][A-Za-z0-9_.\/>-]*$

Self is object of class with env and other members defined.model is used defined deep learning model.

```
self.model = OurModel(input_shape=(self.state_size,), action_space = self.action_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was basic error.:)
'CartPole DQN model' was the name given to model. It is not following regex expression mentioned.

corrected the name and code run successfully.